# Share $rootScope among different module

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm wondering How can angular share $rootScope among multiple module.
Here is what I'm looking for. I've a config service call in run() of mainApp module. Once result is returned I want to store that in root variable so that it can be used in multiple modules.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head ng-app="mainApp">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabpage_1"></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []).run(function($rootScope){
$rootScope.model = {data:"root scope data"};
var domesticTab = document.getElementById("tabpage_1");
angular.bootstrap(domesticTab, ['domestic']);
});
var domestic = angular.module("domestic", []);
domestic.controller("domesticPromoList", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$filter', function ($scope, $rootScope, $filter){
console.log("Get value from root scope: "+ $rootScope.model.data);}]); // Error here $rootscope undefined
```

**Edit:**
I've corrected the mistaken id of div now.

Comment: How are these modules meant to work together? Is `domestic` supposed to be a dependency of `mainApp`? Or are you trying to put two apps on the same page?

Comment: Do they need to be separate modules? Shares data should be encapsulated into one module.

Comment: mainApp and domestic are two separate modules.My basic idea is that domestic module should only be bootstrapped after rootScope in mainApp received the data. I'm newbie to Angular so please suggest any better approach to do that.

Answer (score 0):

sorry have no 50 reputation to add a comment here
but where is `tabpage_1`? if you want `mainApp` and `domestic` module share one rootscope, then they should have some dependencies on each other. from your snippet there is no clue to see this. and if you are mean to share data among directives/controllers, angular service is the one you want.